# Java Spring based open source CRM

Tags: open-source, java, crm

I am looking for well designed open source Java/Spring framework based CRM.

The CRM should not be just a toy project on GitHub but even that I could not find.

It should support around a dozen employees and around 10k customers. Does not matter how much it costs as long as all the code is freely available as open source on github/gitlab. It has VOIP integration so that when a contact number is clicked a call is made. Preferably it has good documentation and is based on Spring or Spring Boot as REST backend and front end is based on framework like react angular vue.